# Dynamically generating a file with javascript?

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm working on a web app for my company that will let us do some image tagging stuff, and I'd like to be able to generates results in the form of a CSV file.  I can do this easily enough by dumping the CSV data to a div or something on the page and having the user copy it out.  I'd rather have them hit the a generate button and have a CSV file downloaded as though they clicked on a link to the result, so they can more easily just save the file somewhere convenient.

Is it possible to simulate this kind of thing with javascript?  I basically want to dynamically generate the file and then let them download it, client side.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a [data: URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) with media type `text/csv`, and either create a link to it, or navigate directly to it, in modern browsers.

It won't work in IE. (IE8 can support `data:` in limited circumstances which don't help you here.) For that browser at least, you'll need to fall back to cut-n-paste or a server backend.

Comment: Bah. Beat me by 14 seconds ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've written a light-weight client-side CSV generator library that might come in handy. Check it out on http://atornblad.se/github/ *(scroll down to the headline saying **Client-side CSV file generator**)*

It requires a functioning `FileSaver` implementation handling calls to `window.saveAs()`. Check out Eli Grey's solution on http://eligrey.com/blog/post/saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

When in place, you simply generate and save CSV files on the fly like this:

```
var propertyOrder = ["name", "age", "height"];

var csv = new Csv(propertyOrder);

csv.add({ name : "Anders",
          age : 38,
          height : "178cm" });

csv.add({ name : "John Doe",
          age : 50,
          height : "184cm" });

csv.saveAs("people.csv");
```